# Linux - mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, database-connection, redhat

I'm using Centos/Redhat 7 on apache and am trying to get the PHP library mssql working. From following other posts, I did the following to get this installed:

```
1) yum install unixODBC unixODBC-devel
2) cd /usr/local/src
3) wget http://ibiblio.org/pub/Linux/ALPHA/freetds/stable/freetds-stable.tgz
4) tar zfvx freetds-stable.tgz
5)cd freetds-*;
5.1) ln -s /usr/local/freetds/lib/  /usr/local/freetds/lib64 (might not be needed)
6) ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/freetds --with-tdsver=8.0 --enable-msdblib --enable-dbmfix --with-gnu-ld; make ; make install 
7) echo "--with-mssql=/usr/local/freetds" >> /var/cpanel/easy/apache/rawopts/all_php5
8) touch /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtds.a
9) touch /usr/local/freetds/include/tds.h
10) /scripts/easyapache
11) WHM > EasyApache3 > Build Apache
12) Check infoPHP() function for "mssql" installation
```

I saw that mssql is installed in the infoPHP function and confirmed that I can access the database using the linux command line:

```
tsql -S sql_server_name -U user_name -P password
```

The problem is when I try to connect using PHP code, I get the error

> Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

What am I missing to get the PHP library mssql to work? The code is listed below to connect but note that I'm transferring code from one server to another so this has worked in the past.

```
$conn = mssql_connect($_config["db_host"],$_config["db_user"],$_config["db_password"]);
mssql_select_db($_config["db_name"],$conn);
```

Note: I already tried to search all other forums with no success on getting this to work.

Comment: Can you perhaps include the PHP code yielding the error in question?

Comment: I included the PHP code but I'm pretty sure it's not the issue because it works in the old server. I'm just trying to transfer code from one server to another and it requires me to install mssql to PHP.

Comment: have you tried to specify port in `$_config["db_host"]`? Like `192.168.0.1:1433`. Also try this command `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1` and then `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db=1`.

Comment: I tried including the port 1433 already and it doesn't work. I have selinux turned off so there isn't any firewall set in the server to test this out.

Comment: That is very strange, in 99% it is firewall blocking apache... ok. Have you tried using `freetds.conf`?

Comment: Yeah, I tried inputting the database server in it with the tds version 8.0. It worked on command line using tsql but when I tried in code,  it didn't work. There's no load time when the error occurs so it seems like it's not even trying to connect.